# HOW do I point the debugger towards UNPACKED version of dll stored on my filesystem during debugging

Tags: ida, ollydbg, debugging, packers, patch-reversing

Here is my problem:

Program P1 launches another program P2.
The P2 program uses a dll DLL1 which is packed using PE Compact.
The DLL1 is obviously unpacked  during run time and a routine inside DLL1 calls another dll DLL2 which is also packed with PE Compact.

### P1->P2->DLL1->DLL2

I have successfully unpacked both the dlls. Now While debugging the OllyDbg shows me "The code is packed, self extracing..." stuff. What I want is to point the OllyDbg towards the unpacked version residing on my filesystem so that a can debug it properly.
How do I d this.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but it seems that you have two original DLLs and those two unpacked on disk. If so, can't you rename the unpacked ones so they are loaded?

Answer (score 0):

As @user45891 commented, replace **DLL1_packed** on disk with **DLL1_unpacked**, and replace **DLL2_packed** on disk with **DLL2_unpacked**.

(@user45891, feel free to post the same answer as this, and I'll delete my answer so that you can get credit as the "first responder".)